# How to run visual studio 2017 API Project via IP address with windows 10 operating system, I am facing lot of problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, windows-10, ip-address

I have to try so many solutions but no one solves my problem, I need to run my visual studio API project in IP address( like `192.168.1.8:7832/`), but at the same time this same project working as well in `localhost:7832`

I have to follow this following steps...

1. Change my `applicationhost.config` file like this

   ```
   <bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1407:192.168.1.8" />
   </bindings>
   ```
2. Then run the following comments cmd promt

   > netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.8:1407/ user=everyone

This just tells `OK`

3. Finally, run the following comment

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=1234 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
   ```

but response is **Service UnAvailable**

Please help me someone, Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: No there is any solution received yet.

Comment: You can accept my solution if it works for you !
Or update with a comment !

Comment: @Raja, Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I received the same **Service Unavailable** error. It was due to mistaken edit.

I was actually editing the `applicationhost.config` of the IIS Express located in Documents -> IISExpress -> config.

The actual file that needs to be edited is located in Project Folder -> .vs -> config. The .vs is a hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution,
If you want to run the project from both **localhost** and **Ip-address**,

Follow these steps:

1) Click on **IIS site** for that project and click on **Bindings** in the rightmost-pane, and click on **Add...**.

2) Type the **IP address** you wish to bind it to, and then add a **port** you wish to use to access it on **local network**, Leave the **Host Name** *blank*.

3) Click **ok** and try to run that project through that **IP-address** and the **port** in the browser. The project should load as expected.

4) If you want to allow that **port** through firewall for local network, add it as a **Inbound-Rule in Firewall**.

NOTE: No changes required in **application.config**.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Your answer is for IIS Server but Visual Studio 2017 uses IIS Express.